# Properties bar shrank (ate magic mushrooms?)

Tags: properties

I just signed up since I'm new to Blender. Did some work in gMax.
At some point the property bar appeared tiny and hardly readable. The other bars are ok-
If I open earlier saves the bar is normal.
Thanks
TOM

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzRWn.png)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your mouse cursor is hovering the desired editor or area, then press <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> or <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> (plus and minus sign from the numeric keyboard on the right) to zoom in or out of the interface.

[image]

Comment: Thanks soooo much! I must have shrunk it accidentally while working on something else. TOM

Comment: You can also use ctrl-MMB like you would in the viewport. This offers finer-grained control.

Comment: @ThomasFrede If the answer helped you consider upvoting it, and if it solved your problem optionally mark it as accepted